# Using Unity, how do I resolve a name value to a static class property?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container, unity2.0

I have a project which has multiple Resource (resx) files along with the accompanying .designer.cs generated files.  Each of these classes has a public static property of type [System.Resources.ResourceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.aspx).

What I can't seem to figure out is how to get the configuration right for unity so that I can resolve it and execute.  Obviously, the code below will not work - since it will not let me register the object that way.

```
public static string GetStringValue(name, tokenName)
{ 
   using (IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer())
   {
        container.LoadConfiguration("ResourceManagers");
        var resolvedManager = container.Resolve<ResourceManager>(name);
        return resolvedManager.GetString(tokenName);
   }
}
```

And given the following configuration...

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <assembly name="Web" />
    <container name="ResourceManagers">
      <register name="Manager1" mapTo="Web.Manager1Strings.ResourceManager" type="System.Resources.ResourceManager" />
    </container>
  </unity>
```

here is the designer code - this is generated by codedom.

```
public class Manager1Strings 
{
    ...
        [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        public static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {
            get {
                if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null)) {
                    global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("Web.Resources.Manager1.Manager1Strings", typeof(Manager1Strings).Assembly);
                    resourceMan = temp;
                }
                return resourceMan;
            }
        }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Side note: creating and configuring a new container on every call to GetStringValue is going to be **very** expensive. Resolve is thread safe, so you could create and configure the container once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I was able to resolve this issue but it was only because I had control over the generation of the designer files (CodeDom).

In summary:

1. I created an interface which had 1 method "GetString"
2. I tweaked the CodeDom logic ([similar to this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ResourceClassGenerator.aspx)) to implement the interface.
3. I was then able to resolve instances of the interface via unity